# php FTP transfer goes wrong (corrupted files)

Tags: php, ftp, firewall

We got the following situation:

We have an application server located in a datacenter. At this server TIFF files in faxformat are generated. The faxserver is located in the customers office. The only way to put the files from the applicationserver to the faxserver is with ftp. In certain configurations the files get corrupted when sending it with plain PHP FTP commands.

---

**Appserver --> ADSL with simple router --> faxserver**

Sending TIFF files to an old fax server via an ADSL line with a very simple router from an application server: this goes fine.

**Appserver --> fiber with advanced firewall --> faxserver**

Sending TIFF files to an old fax server via a fiber line with an advanced firewall from the same application server: this goes wrong. Larger files will become corrupted.

**Appserver --> fiber --> gateway server at remote location --> fiber with advanced firewall --> faxserver**

Getting TIFF files from the same application server to a local server via a fiber connection and than sending it to the faxserver on another location via fiber and the advanced firewall: this goes fine

**Appserver --> fiber with advanced firewall --> gateway server at customer location  --> faxserver**

Getting TIFF files from the same application server to a local server via the fiber connection with the advanced firewall and than sending it to the faxserver on the same local network:  this goes wrong, we get corrupted files again.

---

So it looks like we have a problem with the advanced firewall in the middle but when my gateway server is on a remote location it works fine. The code on the gateway server is the same (only IP addresses changed).
The engineer who manages the firewall asured me that all ports are open for the ip addresses concerned.

We use simple ftp_put commands (binary mode). The faxserver is very simple and I can't change any FTP settings.

Hope someone has an idea how to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Frank

Comment: Have you tried doing a binary comparison of the original and damaged files? I my experience that often gives a hint on what's going on. And if you say "advanced firewall", what kind of device do you mean?

Comment: When it goes wrong, check the sizes in bytes of the sent and recieved files to see if they are grossly different or just a few bytes or even the same size. It may give some indication of the problem.

Comment: Also, try `uuencoding` the files prior to transfer in case something in the path is not 8-bit clean.

Comment: It is a Fortinet 60d firewall. Because the customer complained about the speed of their internet sometime ago I was searching and found this: https://forum.fortinet.com/tm.aspx?m=105411 I asked them to let this check first. After that I will start with uuencoding the files. And let you guys know about the results. Thanks for supporting right now.